# ords database not mapped an database

Tags: tomcat, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I'm trying to configure Oracle Apex 5 and ORDS to work with Tomcat. I managed to complete all steps as per the Oracle docs instruction, however when I try to access ORDS using `http://localhost:8080/ords/` it gives me the error:

> 404 Not Found
>
> The request could not be mapped to any database. Check the request URL is correct, and that URL to database mappings have been correctly configured

Please support, standalone is working.

Oracle: 11g
OS: Linux
Tomcat: 7 (running)

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem by performing the following steps when I found that the ORDS suddenly stops working and encounter 404 error on the login page. Hope it might help!

When you have 404, it could happen to be that there's a problem with the user password expiration.

1. Check if you have any user that’s expired/lock:

   SELECT username, account_status, created, lock_date, expiry_date FROM dba_users WHERE account_status != 'OPEN';
2. Then perform a bunch of “alter user xxx identified as xxxx account unlock”.
3. After you have open every necessary user account, perform the following in your console as administrator:

   Java -jar ords.war setup

   Net stop tomcat8

   Net start tomcat8

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by ensuring that the  hostname in the setup process (`java -jar ords.war setup`) was exactly the same as that in the tnsnames.ora listing for that service. The values localhost and dns1.uk2.net.xxxxxxx.co.uk were not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the answer ? I doubt the ords.war was not able to find the configuration folder and caused the 404 error. What is the output from `java -jar ords.war configdir` ? If it is a relative path run `java -jar ords.war configdir full_path` to change it to a full_path and use the new ords.war so ords.war under webapps can

Comment: I had to redo all steps and then discovered there were permission issues for the folders. Again was stuck with image folder not recognizing issue which was solved by renaming /i/ to /images/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by unlocking the apex user (APEX_190200 in my case) and then restarted tomcat... Simple!

Comment: The internal APEX user (APEX_190200) should not be unlocked, see here: https://dsavenko.me/how-apex-executes-sql-statements-without-having-permissions/

Answer (score 0):

First of all this problem can be caused by many reasons: one of them is that if database was started after tomcat has started (this can be solved by restart of tomcat), can also be caused by misconfiguration of ords (config of connection to database), this error also if database is down or due to listener issues.

**For me** I am using ords 22 and oracle 21c and tomcat 8 web server (tomcat 10 has problem with ords 22) and linux centos 7.

**Simply**

Problem solved by generating ords.war file (after ords install and configuration) as follow:

-First Nagigate to ords bin directory i.e: /u01/ords/bin then:

```
./ords war ords.war
```

the above command generated ords.war file in the same directory. I then copied it to tomcat webapp direcory

```
cp ords.war /opt/tomcat/ords.war
```

**In Details:**
The of setup I followed from start to end (except the solution of this problem not mentioned in bellow urls)

**First:** Setup tomcat Followed steps here:

> https://tecadmin.net/install-tomcat-9-on-centos-8/

**Second:** Downloaded and installed ords as here:

> https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-installation-on-tomcat-22-onward#ords-repair

**Finally:** generation of ords.war as mentioned above to overcome this error:

```
The request could not be mapped to any database... etc
```

I had problem with connection to database also that says:

> The connection pool named: default is a template pool and cannot be
> connected to directly.

Solved by uninstalling ords

```
${ORDS_HOME}/bin/ords --config ${ORDS_CONFIG} uninstall
```

and delete of `/u01/ords/config/database/` directory.

**Note:**
Don't forget to restart tomcat after any modification of ords configuration.